# How to combine 2 conditional count queries into a single query?

Tags: sql, count

I want to combine these two queries to get same result.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    Rollnumber, PapersetName,
    COUNT(*) as 'Wrongattempt'
FROM Student_data
WHERE Qs = 0
GROUP BY Rollnumber, PapersetName


SELECT 
    Rollnumber, PapersetName,
    COUNT(*) as 'Correct'
FROM Student_data
WHERE Qs = 1
GROUP BY Rollnumber, PapersetName
```

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks @Akina and @gotqn for helping in this...here is the answer

```
SELECT Rollnumber
      ,PapersetName
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Qs = 1 THEN  1  END) AS 'Correct'
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Qs = 0 THEN  1  END) AS 'Wrongattempt'
FROM DB_name
GROUP BY Rollnumber
        ,PapersetName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Rollnumber
      ,PapersetName
      ,SUM(IIF(Qs = 1, 1, 0)) AS 'Correct'
      ,SUM(IIF(Qs = 0, 1, 0)) AS 'Wrongattempt'
FROM Student_data
GROUP BY Rollnumber
        ,PapersetName;
```

If you are using version of SQL Server other then SQL Server 2012+ and `IIF` function is not supported, you can use `CASE WHEN` like this:

```
SELECT Rollnumber
      ,PapersetName
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Qs = 1 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Correct'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Qs = 0 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Wrongattempt'
FROM Student_data
GROUP BY Rollnumber
        ,PapersetName;
```

Comment: ok thanks ...if i want  COUNT can i use COUNT  instead of SUM in that mentioned above syntax by you

Comment: In MySQL `..., SUM(Qs = 1) AS 'Correct', ...` is enough.

Comment: @SekharUrs *if i want COUNT can i use COUNT instead of SUM in that mentioned above syntax by you* Easily. Simply remove ELSE part:`..., COUNT(CASE WHEN Qs = 1 THEN 1 END) AS 'Correct', ...`. You may use any non-NULL literal instead of `1` in this case...